# Java contains doesn't work as expected because "someString" != "someString"

Tags: java, string, list, equals, contains

I want check whether a String value `val` is contained within a List of Strings lets call it stringList.

I am doing this

```
if(stringList.contains(val)){
  System.out.println("The value is in there");
}
else{
  System.out.println("There's no such value here");
}
```

But it always seems to be that the value is not included. Is this because two String values that have the same characters are not actually equal? For a "home-made" class I could implement hashCode() and equals() and fix this, what can I do for String data?

EDIT:

The way I am getting val is outlined here:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    stringList.add("PDT");
stringList.add("LDT");
stringList.add("ELNE");

String myFile = "/folder/myFile";
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(myFile);
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(input), ',','"', 1);
String[] nextLine;
try {
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    if (nextLine != null) {
        if (nextLine[6] != null){
          String val = nextLine[6];
            if(stringList.contains(val)){
            System.out.println("Success");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get this `val` from? it might be an encoding problem

Comment: And additionally to Binyamins question: What runtime type is stringList?

Comment: It's taken from a .csv file, so you may be correct. Is there anything I can do - can I force the encoding to be the same for both.

Comment: Could you show some context to that code fragment containing the construction/declaration/type of `val`?

Comment: Yes I will do that, I'd also like to say ... I've used val.equals(aValThatIsInStringList) ... that is I've used equals to compare with the individual items in the stringList ... I would imagine if it were encoding related this wouldn't work (but I a not sure about that)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ArrayList.contains()` uses `Object.equals()` to check for equality (`hashCode()` is not involved in `List`). This works well for strings. Probably, your string really isn't contained in the list...

You've probably overlooked some whitespace or upper/lower-case or encoding difference...

Comment: There seems to be a problem with special characters, for example contains works fine for `mySet.contains("familia")`, but not for `mySet.contains("família")`. The list (in my case I used a `Set`) contains both elements.

Answer (score 5):

That doesn’t sound right: `contains` uses `equals` rather than `==`, so if the string is in the list, it should be found.  This can be verified in the `indexOf` method of the superclass [AbstractList](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractList.java) used by `ArrayList`.

Following your edit, make sure you `trim` strings before doing `contains`, as otherwise they may contain the `newline` character(s).

Answer (score 4):

More code please!

This works:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Contains {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        stringList.add("someString");
        String val = new String("someString");
        if (stringList.contains(val)) {
            System.out.println("The value is in there");
        } else {
            System.out.println("There's no such value here");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, first make the check more concrete by iterating the list and checking each element separately. Than, when you hit the elements that you are expecting to be equal, This is what you are supposed to be looking at. Check to see if they are really equal. Maybe there is a case difference? (or some other elusive but plain difference like white space?)

Comment: Thanks, I am actually using trim() as well in my application code. Given all the responses I can understand that it's probably a minor difference rather than a fundamental problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to override `equals()`, so that you can specify which property needs to compare equality .... :P